# Show/hide script cannot hide again on 2nd click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I used jquery show/hide in many place in my web. every where its work well but in this case its not hide again in 2nd click.

here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/er9e72ww/

show/hide code

```
$('#uploadMedia').livequery("click",function(){
  $('#show_img_upload_div').slideToggle('slow');
  $("#comment").focus();
  $('.upfrm').show();
  $('#submit').hide();
});
```

Comment: Toggle other class and id too..
$('.upfrm').toggle();
$('#submit').toggle();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** in jquery to hide and show repeatedly

```
$('#uploadMedia').livequery("click",function(){
$('#show_img_upload_div').slideToggle('slow');
$("#comment").focus();
$('.upfrm').toggle();
$('#submit').toggle();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/er9e72ww/1/)**

Comment: @koch Glad to help you , if you satisfied  this ans then give the accepted

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is you are `hiding/showing` `submit/upfrm`  but not `showing/hide` it again.use toggle for this:

```
$('.upfrm').toggle();
$('#submit').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.slideToggle('slow');` instead of `show()` and `hide()` like:

```
$('#uploadMedia').livequery("click", function () {
    $('#show_img_upload_div').slideToggle('slow');
    $("#comment").focus();
    $('.upfrm').slideToggle('slow');
    $('#submit').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I already accepted a ans. But I like yours one and I will use it too. Thank you so again.

Comment: I have not so reputation to vote, but i will upvote it in feature. Thank you sir